# android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference, when trying to access a method in an activity through a java class

Tags: java, firebase, android-intent, firebase-mlkit

I am running a basic Face detection app in real time, and im counting the number of times it detects a face in the FaceDetectionProcessor.java class ( used this as reference --> https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/java )  and at a particular count value it makes an object of the Activity using the FaceDetectionProcessor.java object to call a method to start a new activity, and there it crashes.

tried FaceDetectActivity.this, simply this, getApplicationContext(), even a global Context object which sets its value to "this" in the onCreate() of the FaceDetectActivity

```
public class FaceDetectActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
    private static final String FACE_DETECTION = "Face Detection";
    private static final String TAG = "LivePreviewActivity";
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUESTS = 1;
    private CameraSource cameraSource = null;
    private CameraSourcePreview preview;
    private GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay;
    private String selectedModel = FACE_DETECTION;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
.
.
.
.
}


private void createCameraSource(String model) {
        // If there's no existing cameraSource, create one.
        if (cameraSource == null) {
            cameraSource = new CameraSource(this, graphicOverlay);
        }
        try {
            switch (model) {
                case FACE_DETECTION:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Using Face Detector Processor");
                    cameraSource.setMachineLearningFrameProcessor(new FaceDetectionProcessor());
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unknown model: " + model);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "can not create camera source: " + model);
        }
    }

public void alertAndMove(){
        Intent i=new Intent(FaceDetectActivity.this,SelectingParty.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

```
public class FaceDetectionProcessor extends VisionProcessorBase<List<FirebaseVisionFace>> {
    int count=0;

    private static final String TAG = "FaceDetectionProcessor";

    private final FirebaseVisionFaceDetector detector;

    public FaceDetectionProcessor() {
        FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions options =
                new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                        .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                        .enableTracking()
                        .build();

        detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(options);
    }

    .
    .
    .
    . 
    . 
    .
    .

    @Override
    protected void onSuccess(
            @NonNull List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces,
            @NonNull FrameMetadata frameMetadata,
            @NonNull GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay) {
        graphicOverlay.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
            FirebaseVisionFace face = faces.get(i);
            FaceGraphic faceGraphic = new FaceGraphic(graphicOverlay);
            graphicOverlay.add(faceGraphic);
            faceGraphic.updateFace(face, frameMetadata.getCameraFacing());
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Face detected and count= "+count);
            count++;
            if(count>=15)
                new FaceDetectActivity().alertAndMove();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Face detection failed " + e);
    }
}
```

when new FaceDetectActivity().alertAndMove() is called, the app crashes in alertAndMove() at the line Intent i=new Intent(FaceDetectActivity.this,......)

What's immensely frustrating about the situation, is that the same logic worked on the same code, on my friends laptop where I had initially tested the logic.

Comment: This is almost certainly not what you want to do: `new FaceDetectActivity().alertAndMove();`  You're supposed to let Android control activity object instances - you don't create them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the FaceDetectActivity I sent the Intent and context to FaceDetectionProcessor.java:

```
case FACE_DETECTION:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Using Face Detector Processor");
                    Intent i=new Intent( this,SelectingParty.class);
                    cameraSource.setMachineLearningFrameProcessor(new FaceDetectionProcessor(this,i));
                    break;
```

And in the constructor of the FaceDetectionProcessor.java I initialized the instance Context obj and Intent intent as follows:

```
public FaceDetectionProcessor(Context obj, Intent intent) {
        this.obj=obj;
        this.intent=intent;
.
.
.
```

Finally in the onSuccess method in FaceDetectionProcessor.java I did:

```
if(count>=15){
                obj.startActivity(intent);
            }
```

That's it ! I However still can't close the previous activities, any comments suggesting how I could achieve would be of great help ! 
P.S. I tried CLEAR_TASK, CLEAR_TOP, NEW_TASK, didn't work, but I could be missing something.